# Push View Controller from IBAction

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationitem, pushviewcontroller

In a NavigationController I have an TabBarController. I have a custom class for TabBarController's NavigationItem, which is subclass of UINavigationItem. My NavigationItem has a TabBarButtonItem which contains an UIButton. I have defined an action for this button. My question is how can I programmatically make a push to an other view from this action? How can I get in this class the navigation controller? Or exists an other way for this?

in .h:

```
@interface CustomNavigationItem : UINavigationItem
{
    IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *barbtnApply;
    IBOutlet UIButton *btnApply;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIBarButtonItem *barbtnApply;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIButton *btnApply;
-(IBAction)actionApply:(id)sender;

@end
```

in .m:

```
@implementation CustomNavigationItem

@synthesize btnApply = _btnApply;
@synthesize barbtnApply = _barbtnApply;

-(IBAction)actionApply:(id)sender
{
    btnApply = sender;
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"test" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    //push to other view
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should declare a delegate and call it on the button method.

in your CustomNavigationItem.h

```
@protocol CustomNavigationItemDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)shouldPushViewController;

@end

@interface CustomNavigationItem : UINavigationItem{
      id<CustomNavigationItemDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<CustomNavigationItemDelegate> delegate;
```

in your CustomNavigationItem.m

```
@implementation CustomNavigationItem

@synthesize btnApply = _btnApply;
@synthesize barbtnApply = _barbtnApply;
@synthesize delegate;

 -(IBAction)actionApply:(id)sender
 {
     btnApply = sender;
     [self.delegate shouldPushViewController];
}
@end
```

in your viewcontroller.m

set the delegate

in .h

```
@interface MyViewController:UIViewController <CustomNavigationItemDelegate>
```

in .m

```
 mynavigationItem.delegate = self;
```

and implement the method

```
-(void)shouldPushViewController{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewControllerToPass animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code. The problem is that I don't have a viewcontroller, I have a tabbarcontroller which has this navigationitem... here is a screenshot from my storyboard: http://postimage.org/image/sv6elwmcz/

Comment: then implement the delegate where you want to push the other viewcontroller, it was just an example